# Wrap received slots (vnodes) in anonymous component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I would like to receive two named slots `slotOne` and `slotTwo`. These are located in the child component at `this.$scopedSlots.slotOne` and `this.$scopedSlots.slotTwo` and contain vnodes. How can I wrap these slots (vnodes) in a new component so that I can conditionally render them like this:

Child Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <keep-alive>
      <component :is="wrapperComponentContainingProperSlot"></component>
    </keep-alive>
  </div>
</template>
```

Parent Component:

```
<template>
  <child>
    <template v-slot:slotOne>
      ...
    </template>
    <template v-slot:slotTwo>
      ...
    </template>
  </child>
</template>
```

I'm guessing the core of this question is, how do I create a component from vnodes inside of another component?

Comment: Where should `slotOne` and `slotTwo` be rendered within the child component? You aren't using them anywhere in the template.

Comment: It can be done.  But what would be the benefit over placing `<component :is="wrapperComponentContainingProperSlot">` in the parent instead?

Comment: The child is trying to encapsulate the logic used to determine which slot to render (in my case, based on whether or not we are running on a mobile device), and also, we would like to add `keep-alive` functionality to each slot. To my understanding, that would require wrapping `slotOne` and `slotTwo` into their own (anonymous?) component - I just have no idea how to do that lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe my motivation for desiring to implement this was based on the false premise that `<keep-alive>` is NOT destroyed when its parent is destroyed. This was not the case. Nevertheless, I did figure out how to wrap slots into their own components, both anonymous and named.

Child component:

```
<template>
  <component :is="componentToRender"></component>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {
  computed: {
    componentToRender() {
      return this.showSlotOnesGlobally
        ? new this.SlotOneWrapperComponent(this)
        : new this.SlotTwoWrapperComponent(this);
    },
  },
  /* Assume a parent further up in the tree provided this data */
  inject: {
    showSlotOnesGlobally: 'showSlotOnesGlobally'
  },
  methods: {
    SlotOneWrapperComponent(context) {
      return Vue.component('SlotOneContentWrapper', {
        render() {
          return context.$scopedSlots.slotOne();
        },
      });
    },
    SlotTwoWrapperComponent(context) {
      return Vue.component('SlotTwoContentWrapper', {
        render() {
          return context.$scopedSlots.slotTwo();
        },
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <child>
    <template v-slot:slotOne>
      ...
    </template>
    <template v-slot:slotTwo>
      ...
    </template>
  </child>
</template>
```

To make them anonymous components, simply replace `Vue.component('SlotOneContentWrapper',`   and `Vue.component('SlotTwoContentWrapper',`  with `Vue.extend(`.

If anyone can offer a more concise solution, that would be wonderful.